# Get jQuery variable in php without $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using the `dialog()` function from the jQuery UI. This pops up a dialog where the user will select a value. This value then needs to be returned in the PHP page.

This is my jQuery code

```
$(function() {
var portal_id = $( "#portal_id" ),
  allFields = $( [] ).add( portal_id );

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Selecteer afbeelding": function() {
      var bValid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      bValid = "portal_id";

      if ( bValid ) {
        $( "#portal_id" ).append( "<tr>" + "<td>" + portal_id.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>");
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
});

$( "#select_portal" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

This returns a value in my php:

```
<table id="portal_id" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<tr class="ui-widget-header ">
<th>Portal_id</th>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<!--- The value is returned here as: <tr><td>portal_id.val()</td></tr> --->
</table>
```

How can I get the portal_id.val() to return in for example:

```
 <input type="text" id="name" value="portal_id.val()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy the value from `#portal_id` into `#name`:

```
$("#name").val(portal_id.val());
```

Comment: Nothing happens if my line to that bit of code. am I writing my input type wrong? <input type="text" id="name" value="" />

Comment: Made a mistake, it should be `.val()`, not `.value`.

Comment: Follow up: how can I get this value into: <?php find_by_id($value) ?>

Comment: You can't get it into PHP. PHP runs on the server when the page is being created, it's all done when the page is shown in the browser. To get inputs back to PHP you have to submit a form or use AJAX.

Comment: I cannot have the dialog submit a form as it will clear all the form data already filled in from the form where the dialog() is called upon. I've got absolutely zero knowledge of AJAX.

Comment: Then I guess this is a good time for you to learn AJAX. I'm not going to try to teach it to you here.

Comment: Surething :) not asking you for that. Thanks for your help.